# React useState is not re-rendering while it is referring cloned array by spreading

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to sort an array and reflect its sort result immediately by useState hook.
I already new that react is detecting its state change by `Object.is()`, so trying to spread array before using `useState` like below;

```js
const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([...book.reviews]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const sortedReviews = [...reviews]
            .sort((review1: IReview, review2: IReview) =>
                sortBy(review1, review2, sortRule));

        setReviews([...sortedReviews])
        }, [sortRule])
```

After sorting I checked the value of variable `sortedReviews` and it was sorted as expected, but react did not re-render the page so this sorting was not reflected to UI.

I already searched solutions and it seemed many could solve the issue by spreading an array to before calling `useState` like this stack overflow is explaining:  [Why is useState not triggering re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266575/why-is-usestate-not-triggering-re-render).
However, on my end it is not working.. Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you!

[Added]
And my rendering part is like below;

```
    <>
        {
            sortedReviews
                .map((review: IReview) => (
                    <ReviewBlock id={review.id}
                                 review={review}
                                 targetBook={book}
                                 setTargetBook={setBook}/>
                ))
        }
    </>
```

Comment: what make you sure that your component is not re-rendering?

Comment: Hi miraj, I thought it was not re-rendered because the order was not sorted as the array `sortedReviews `. For example, when I sorted  `sortedReviews ` based on CreatedDate, it was not ordered that way on the page while the value of the variable was. Am i making sense?

Comment: you put `sortRule` in the dependency array. make sure it does not change in every re-render. if so then your component will fall in a loop.

Comment: another thing is `setReviews` will be called asynchronously. it may set the given value before your `sort` function finish.

Comment: but I confirmed `sortedReviews` was sorted as expected, so `setReviews` should receive ideal ordered arrays, so sorting should be processed within `useEffect` as expected..

Comment: i got your point. the problem is not with sortReviews. `setReviews` is getting `reviews` as you initialized `sortReviews` with it.

Comment: Thank you for checking further. I tried as `const sortedReviews =[...reviews].sort.....`, to make `sortedReviews` from cloned array, not exact from `reviews`. However, I am still experiencing the same issue...

Comment: oops! missed the `.`

Comment: `reviews` is missing in your dependency list.

Comment: I don't think we need to put `reviews` in dep list of `useEffect` as it should be updated only when `sortRule` would be updated. I checked useEffect is working as expected for sorting (i.e. `reviews` has the correctly sorted items). My problem here is this sorting on `reviews` is not reflected on the page as `useState` is not triggering re-render..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes I facing this issue too, in my case I just "force" render calling callback.

**First solution:**

```
const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([...book.reviews]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const sortedReviews = [...reviews]
            .sort((review1: IReview, review2: IReview) =>
                sortBy(review1, review2, sortRule));

        setReviews(()=> [...sortedReviews]) // <-- Here
        }, [sortRule])
```

**second solution:**
You can use **useRef** to get data in real time, see below:

```
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([...book.reviews]);
    const reviewsRef = useRef();
     
            useEffect(() => {
                const sortedReviews = [...reviews]
                    .sort((review1: IReview, review2: IReview) =>
                        sortBy(review1, review2, sortRule));
        
                setReviewRef([...sortedReviews]) 
                }, [sortRule])

function setReviewRef(data){
       setReview(data);
       reviewsRef.current = data;
    }
```

So, instead use the state **reviews** use **reviewsRef.current** as u array

I hope you can solve this!

Comment: You made my day!!!! now it is rendering as the array is sorted. I had no idea of this trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I appreciate it! Thx!

P.S: I added another solution, you can try to use on future xD

Answer (score 1):

When components don't re-render it is almost always due to mutations of state.  Here you are calling a mutating operation `.sort` on `reviews`.  You would need to spread the array **before** you mutate it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const sortedReviews = [...reviews].sort((review1: IReview, review2: IReview) =>
    sortBy(review1, review2, sortRule)
  );

  setReviews(sortedReviews);
}, [sortRule]);
```

But there are other issues here.  `reviews` is not a dependency of the useEffect so we would want to use a `setReviews` callback like `setReviews(current => [...current].sort(...`.

In general sorted data makes more sense as a `useMemo` than a `useState`.  The `sortRule` is a state and the `sortedReviews` are derived from it.

The way that you are calling `sortBy` as a comparer function feels a bit off.  Maybe it's just a confusing name?

Also you should not need to include the type `IReview` in your callback if `book` is typed correctly as `{reviews: IReview[]}`.

If you include your `sortBy` function and `sortRule` variable then I can be of more help.  But here's what I came up with.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";

type IReview = {
    rating: number;
}

type Book = {
    reviews: IReview[]
}

type SortRule = string; // just a placeholder - what is this really?

declare function sortBy(a: IReview, b: IReview, rule: SortRule): number;

const MyComponent = ({book}: {book: Book}) => {
    const [sortRule, setSortRule] = useState("");

    const reviews = book.reviews;

    const sortedReviews = useMemo( () => {
        return [...reviews].sort((review1, review2) =>
            sortBy(review1, review2, sortRule)
        );
    }, [sortRule, reviews]);
...
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wRpjxm)

Comment: Hi Linda, thank you so much for checking.

Comment: Hi Linda, thank you so much for checking.
`SortRule ` is actually enum, and default is like(0);

```enum SortRule {
    like,
    new
}```

Comment: I tried as you kindly showed, and it almost working but rendering part is not working still.
    I confirmed `sortedReviews ` is processed as expected when switching the selector, but after switching `SortRule` to new from like, UI is still showing default order; based on Like.
I updated the above question desc to add my rendering part referring `sortedReviews`. May i ask your opinion if this part could be causing the issue?

Comment: You probably want to add `key={review.id}` to `<ReviewBlock />` but I don't think that's your problem and I don't see anything else wrong in the render.