# props change does not re-render child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

im passing a variable and two functions that changes the state of the variable as props in a child component. when i execute the functions the variable changes its state but the child component does not re-render, knowing that im using the same code in another class that calls the same child component and its working fine.

Here's the functions and the render of the child component.

```
  onRowClickHandle = async (product) => {
     BlockTimer.execute(() => {
       this.props.onViewProductScreen({ product });
     }, 1000);
  };
  
  async componentDidMount(){
    await this.fetchReadLaterBooks();
  }

  async fetchReadLaterBooks(){
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
    const isLoggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
    if (isLoggedIn == 1) {
      await fetch(Config.backendAPI+`/readlater.php?username=${user}&test=1&select`)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((json) => {
          if(json.length != this.state.prodList.length){
            json.map((product, index) => {
              this.state.prodList.push(product.id)
            });
            this.setState({
              prodList:this.state.prodList,
              isLoading:false,
            });
          }
          this.forceUpdate();
        })
        .catch((error) => alert(error));   
    }
  }

  removeReadLater = async (id) => { 
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
    this.setState({
      prodList:this.state.prodList.filter((productId) => productId !== id),
    });
    await fetch(Config.backendAPI+`/readlater.php?username=${user}&idDoc=${id}&delete`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
  }

   addReadLater = async (id) =>{
    try{
      const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
      //insertion dans la liste actuelle des readlater.
      const joined = this.state.prodList.concat(id);
      this.setState({
        prodList:joined,
      });
      //insertion dans la base
      await fetch(Config.backendAPI+`/readlater.php?username=${user}&idDoc=${id}&insert`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch((er) => alert(er));
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <ProdList 
        addReadLater={this.addReadLater}
        removeReadLater={this.removeReadLater}
        readLaterBooks={this.state.prodList}          
        item={item}
        onRowClickHandle={this.onRowClickHandle}          
      />
    );
  };
 

  
   render() {
    const {
      theme: {
        colors: { background, text,
        dark: isDark  },
        
      },
    } = this.props; 

    if(!this.state.isLoading){
      return (
            <View style={{flex:1 ,backgroundColor:background}}>
              <FlatList  
                data={this.props.products}  
                renderItem={this.state.prodList ? this.renderItem : null}
              /> 
            </View>
        );
    }else{
      return <LogoSpinner fullStretch />;
    }
     
   }

  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is useState not triggering re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266575/why-is-usestate-not-triggering-re-render)

Comment: No it does not answer my question unfortunately :(