# In Reactjs, How to handle the restaurantsPhotoList so it is re-rendered properly (the value of the array is already a proper value)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If we see the code below, I have tried following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266575/why-is-usestate-not-triggering-re-render)

The line which has inline comment `// HERE: Display In Console` has return the proper value `Array(29) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]`

Why was the component not rerendered? and how to handle it so it (Line with `// HERE: TSX For restaurantPhotoList` comment) is re-rendered properly? [What I got in the UI is the loading text for some seconds, and then no element after the loading text is finished (There are no photos nor `<h1>There is no photos ...</h1>` element)]

Here is my component `RestaurantDetail`:

```
const RestaurantDetail = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [restaurantsPhotoList, setRestaurantsPhotoList] = useState<any>([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const location = useLocation();
    const restaurantName = location.state?.name;
    const restaurantRating = location.state?.rating;

    useEffect(() => {
        if(id != undefined) {
            loadRestaurantDetails(id.toString());
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.info(restaurantsPhotoList); // HERE: Display In Console
    }, [restaurantsPhotoList])

    const loadRestaurantDetails = (id: string) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const responseRestaurant = getDetailRestaurant(id);
        responseRestaurant.then((res: any) => {
            return res.data;
        }).then((data: any) => {
            setRestaurantsPhotoList(arrayUnique(data.restaurant.photos.concat([...restaurantsPhotoList])));
        }).catch((err: any) => {
            console.error(err.message);
        }).finally(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <section className="flex flex-col justify-start">
                <h1 className="">{restaurantName}</h1>
                <div className="flex flex-row justify-start gap-2">
                    <Star starAmount={Math.floor(restaurantRating/2)}/>
                    <span className="text-sm text-[#888888]">{restaurantRating/2}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="min-h-screen">
                    {
                        isLoading == false ? (
                            // HERE: TSX For restaurantPhotoList
                            restaurantsPhotoList.length != 0 ? (
                                restaurantsPhotoList.map((elmt: any, idx: any) => {
                                    // <img key={idx} src={elmt.src} alt={restaurantName} className="w-52 h-52 rounded-md" draggable={false}/>
                                    <div>
                                        <p key={idx}>{elmt.src}</p>
                                    </div>
                                })
                            ) : (
                                <div className='flex flex-row justify-center w-screen'>
                                    <h1>There is no photo posted by users</h1>
                                </div>
                            )
                        ) : (
                            <div className='flex flex-row justify-center w-screen'>
                                <h1>Loading...</h1>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the map, when you use the {} braces you are forcing something to return and in this case you do not use the return.

To solve it you have two options:

- Do not use braces and use parentheses.
- Inside the braces use the return in parenthesis adding the content.

Example:

```js
restaurantsPhotoList.map((elmt: any, idx: any) => {
    return ( 
        <>    
            <img key={idx} src={elmt.src} alt={restaurantName} className="w-52 h-52 rounded-md" draggable={false}/>
            <div>
                <p key={idx}>{elmt.src}</p>
            </div>
        </>
    )
})
```